# how to import sqlite data from firefox add into core data?

Tags: iphone, core-data

I'm new to programming and my app needs a database that will hold about 2000 names which will load into a table and link to a second view showing address, phone, image, links to web site etc.

I have researched cora data and think this is way to go. I have been following the tutorial by ray wenderlich that have been recommended on this site however I don't understand how to contect my sqlite data base to cora data.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/980/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data

more specifically: In the tutorial it states "You can examine the storeUrl variable to see a full path to where the sqlite backing file resides. So find this and copy it to the directory your Python script is in."

I can find the full path to the sqlite file but what is the python script and am I heading in the right direction.

Any help would be great! I have been working on this for days.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you should not manipulate the sqlite database which is used by CoreData directly. The reason for this is that the internal table structure of the CoreData sqlite backend is an implementation detail an not public.

So you are left with two possibilities:

1. use the standard C sqlite library to import the database into a real CoreData database and then use CoreData with all its bells and whistles. Remember CoreData **is not a database**.
2. use the sqlite database as it is and use the APIs available for manipulating and fetching data directly. You could not use CoreData in this case but instead use standard SQL to interact with the database. The benefit is that you do not have to keep two databases, the coreData backend and the external sqlite database in sync.

Answer (score 0):

you can follow this tutorial if you want to get data from your sqlite database

http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development-tutorials/iphone-sdk-tutorial-reading-data-from-a-sqlite-database/

look at -(void) checkAndCreateDatabase to get path.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Will this tut work with the fixfox sqlite add on or is the code different and can you update the database at a later date like add additional rows/columns@saadnib

Comment: yes its for firefox sqlite add on and also you can edit the database later.